# How can I generate sql matrix

Tags: sql, sql-server, matrix

How I can create this matrix from the tables in sql query? I have table which show how many goods was sold. I want show title of goods instead id of goods. But it's important that fields toy1, toy2 and toy3 have datatype decimal(20,8)

```
Table 1

id   year   toy1   toy2   toy3
-------------------------------
-1           1      3      2
 1   2016    100    20     50
 2   2017    150    120    40

Table 2

id     toy
---------------
1      doll
2      car
3      bear

Result matrix

 id   year   toy1   toy2   toy3
-------------------------------
-1           doll   bear   car
 1   2016    100    20     50
 2   2017    150    120    40
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: now in test version for ssms, later for oracle

Comment: You should test on the same DBMS that you use for production. Especially with queries like that the solution is highly dependent on the actual DBMS product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `SQL Server` i will do some `left joins`

```
SELECT T.id,
       T.year,
       CASE
           WHEN T1.TOY IS NULL THEN CAST(T.[toy1] AS VARCHAR) ELSE T1.TOY
       END [toy1],
      CASE
           WHEN T2.TOY IS NULL THEN CAST(T.[toy2] AS VARCHAR) ELSE T2.TOY
       END [toy2],
      CASE
           WHEN T3.TOY IS NULL THEN CAST(T.[toy3] AS VARCHAR) ELSE T3.TOY
       END [toy3]

FROM <Table1> T
     LEFT JOIN <Table2> T1 ON T1.ID = T.toy1
     LEFT JOIN <Table2> T2 ON T2.ID = T.toy2
     LEFT JOIN <Table2> T3 ON T3.ID = T.toy3;
```

Result :

```
id  year    toy1    toy2    toy3
-1  NULL    doll    bear    car
1   2016    100     20      50
2   2017    150     120     40
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very bad data model.

A table should represent an entity, such as a toy, an order, yearly sales, ... A column on the other side represents an attribute of that entity, e.g. the toy's name or price, the order's date, the sale's year. In your model you are mixing this. What is "toy1"? A toy ID? An amount? A mix of both it seems. Then your table 2 allows for many, many toys, whereas your table1 allows for only 3. That doesn't match.

What you should have instead:

**table toys**

```
toy_id | name
-------+-----
1      | doll
2      | car
3      | bear
```

**table sales**

```
year | toy_id | amount
2016 | 1      |  100
2016 | 2      |   20
2016 | 3      |   50
2017 | 1      |  150
2017 | 2      |  120
2017 | 3      |   40
```

And you wouldn't write a query to give you the matrix either. You would select the data (e.g. `select * from sales order by year, toy_id`) and have your app handle the display. It is easy to fetch the data in a loop with whatever programming language, be it C#, Visual Basic, Java, PHP, whatever, and display it in a grid.

In an SQL query you must know the columns beforehand, but this is not the case with your matrix output, as you would have to know how many toys are in the toys table before running or even writing the query. Everytime you added a toy, you'd have to alter your query. This is not how relational databases are supposed to work.

Comment: Thanks for your example, I understand it myself. But I don't develop sql.  I work with existing tables. In this case the table is so constructed, moreover all the data is dynamic and the table is constructed using stored procedure

Comment: I am very sorry to hear that. So the table will be modified with every product and one day you may have toy1 to toy5000 for 5000 different products. And you want a query to deal with that? I'd still suggest a programming language and two queries then: `select * from table1`, `select * from table2` with appropriate order by clauses if that eases fetching the data. If there is any chance though to have them change the table design, do so.

Comment: yes, you're right. This was my first decision. I just couldn't do it with datareader etc. and thought about the request. Thank you very much for your help ans advice!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but something like this:

```
SELECT T1.id,
   year, 
   CASE WHEN T1.Toy1 = T2.id AND T1.id=-1 THEN T2.toy
   ELSE T1.Toy1 
   END AS Toy1,
   CASE WHEN T1.Toy2 = T2.id AND T1.id=-1THEN T2.toy
   ELSE T1.Toy2 
   END AS Toy1,
   CASE WHEN T1.Toy3 = T2.id AND T1.id=-1 THEN T2.toy
   ELSE T1.Toy3 
   END AS Toy3
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.id=-1 AND T2.id IN (T1.Toy1, T1.Toy2, T1.Toy3)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to only select the -1 row and apply the algorithms to get the toy names.  That can be `UNION ALL` with the rest of the table that is not the -1 row.

You will have to Cast the output as varchar to mix words and numbers:

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE (id int, [year] int, toy1 int, toy2 int, toy3 int)
DECLARE @table2 TABLE (id int, toy varchar(100))

INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES (-1, null, 1, 3, 2), (1, 2016, 100,20,50), (2,2017,150,120,40)
INSERT INTO @table2 VALUES (1,'doll'), (2,'car'), (3,'bear')

-- for the -1 row
SELECT T1.id, COALESCE(CAST(year as varchar), '') AS year
      ,(SELECT toy FROM @table2 T2 WHERE T2.id = T1.toy1) AS toy1
      ,(SELECT toy FROM @table2 T2 WHERE T2.id = T1.toy2) AS toy2
      ,(SELECT toy FROM @table2 T2 WHERE T2.id = T1.toy3) AS toy3

  FROM @table1 T1
 WHERE T1.id = -1

UNION ALL

--all other rows
SELECT T3.id
      ,CAST(T3.year as varchar) 
      ,CAST(T3.toy1 as varchar)
      ,CAST(T3.toy2 as varchar)
      ,CAST(T3.toy3 as varchar)

  FROM @table1 T3
 WHERE T3.id <> -1
```

Gives output:

```
id  year    toy1    toy2    toy3
-1          doll    bear    car
1   2016    100     20      50
2   2017    150     120     40
```